# Trouble with Syntax for recursive function that runs until a loan balance reaches 0

Tags: python, recursion, syntax

```
SA=1000.00
AI=0.12
MP=100.00
def remainb(x):
if x==0:
    return 0
else: 
    return
    x=(SA+(AI/12)*SA)-MP
    for i in range(x,1000000):
        x=(x+(AI/12)*x)-MP
        CIwoP=(x+(AI/12)*x)-x #interest every month
        ptd=MP*i#payment to date
        #ptdreal=(ptd-CIwoP)
        #rbal=(CIwP-ptd)
        print(i)#payment no.
        print(ptd)#amount paid to date
        print(CIwoP)#interest for that month
        print(x)#balance for each month after payment
        #if rbal==0: return 0
        #return
```

Made multiples attempts at debugging this and have failed repeatedly for hours. Frankly, I am stuck. If anyone can give me advice on how to approach this problem (eg. run the loop until SA==0) I would be eternally grateful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve. Switching to while loop is more appropriate as you're not sure how many times you need to loop. This will continue as long as x greater than 0.

Loop approach

```
x = (SA + (AI / 12) * SA) - MP
payment_number = 0
while x > 0:
    x = (x + (AI / 12) * x) - MP
    CIwoP = (x + (AI / 12) * x) - x  # interest every month
    ptd = MP * payment_number  # payment to date
    payment_number += 1
    print(payment_number)  # payment no.
    print(ptd)  # amount paid to date
    print(CIwoP)  # interest for that month
    print(x)  # balance for each month after payment
```

Recursion approach

```
def remainb(x, payment_number=0):
    if x < 0: return
    x = (x + (AI / 12) * x) - MP
    CIwoP = (x + (AI / 12) * x) - x  # interest every month
    ptd = MP * payment_number  # payment to date
    payment_number += 1
    print(payment_number)  # payment no.
    print(ptd)  # amount paid to date
    print(CIwoP)  # interest for that month
    print(x)  # balance for each month after payment
    remainb(x, payment_number)
```

Just to mention, it's a good habit to use good descriptive variable names instead of x, and i :)